# For the two errors of updateview, Django

Tags: python, django

I will write down the code first and explain it below.

views.py

```
class comment_update(UpdateView):
  model = Comment
  fields = '__all__'
  # success_url = reverse_lazy('board')

  def get(self, request, pk):
      com = Comment.objects.filter(id=pk)
                  
      return render(self.request, 'comment_edit.html',{
          'com' : com
      })
    
  def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.board.pk})
```

urls.py

```
path('board/comment/<int:pk>/update/', views.comment_update.as_view(), name="comment_update")
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'comment_update' i.id %}">
```

If i don't use fields in the situation as the code above,

A Error occurs.
When fields are used, an error of B occur.
In the case of B, why does the `success_url` and `get_sufficiency_url` not work?

**A**

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /board/comment/4/update/
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of comment_update) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
```

**B**

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /board/comment/4/update/
board/comment_form.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically circumventing all the Django builtin functionality of the `UpdateView` by overriding `get`.

Don't do that, you're crippling yourself.

```
class CommentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = '__all__'
    context_object_name = 'com'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('board_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.board.pk})

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # debugging
        logger.debug('invalid form', form.errors)
        return form
```

Should be sufficient to have the following context variables available:

```
{% form.as_p %}
{% form.errors %} <-- display this at least for debugging
{% com %} <-- this is your object (or use 'object')
```

Do also check the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

The magic that adds your object to the context:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#singleobjectmixin - or have a look at its source code, it's not too complicated.

Comment: i don't understand. Then, how should I do with the 'com' context that I sprayed with the render in the code above?

Comment: You don't need to call `render` explicitly. This is done by Django. Use the code snippet I pasted, it should be sufficient.

Comment: Okay get seems to work. However, there is no response when post (No errors, no correction)

Comment: Most probably, your form is invalid but you are not displaying the errors. I have added an override for `form_invalid` to show how you can debug it. You should display errors to the users, though - `form.errors` are all errors but the form allows you to access the errors on field level as well. Please check the documentation.

Comment: AttributeError : 'CommentForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: and I didn't make a form.